# Passing default value inside arrow function

Tags: javascript

Im working with this part of code which one render simple loading bar

```
const smallSpinner = document.getElementById('spinner-small').getContext('2d');
let pointToFill = 4.72;
let cw = smallSpinner.canvas.width; //Return canvas width
let ch = smallSpinner.canvas.height; //Return canvas height
let diff;

let = fillSmallSpinner = (startingPointSmall = 0) => {
    diff = ((startingPointSmall / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10);

    smallSpinner.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

    smallSpinner.lineWidth = 5;

    smallSpinner.strokeStyle = '#d40511';

    /* smallSpinner.textAlign = 'center';

     smallSpinner.font = "25px monospace"; 

     smallSpinner.fillText(no + '%', 50, 55); */ //uncomment this if you need percent progress inside spinner

    smallSpinner.beginPath();

    smallSpinner.arc(50, 50, 40, pointToFill, diff / 10 + pointToFill);

    smallSpinner.stroke();


    if (startingPointSmall >= 100) {
        clearTimeout(fill);
    }
    startingPointSmall++;
}

let small = setInterval(fillSmallSpinner, 50);
```

The point is that when "startingPointSmall" is defined like normal variable

```
let startingPointSmall = 0;
```

it works totaly fine but i want to make this a little bit more usable and pass the starting point as a function parameter. When i do this like this with predefined starting point on 0% it doesnt work. Can someone explain me how to fix this?

Comment: please elaborate on "it doesn't work", i.e. explain the behaviour you _do_ see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time that `setInterval` queues up a call to `fillSmallSpinner` it will receive its default parameter - over and over!

A more common pattern is to wrap the function in a way that preserves the desired variable's scope:

```
const startFiller(callback, interval = 50, start = 0) {
    let current = startPoint;
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
        callback(current++);
        if (current >= 100) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, interval);
});

startFiller(fillSmallSpinner);
```

You would then remove any existing timer-related logic from your `fillSmallSpinner` function.   This approach has the added benefit of *Separation of Concerns* - if you decide you want to use a different function to render your spinner it no longer needs to concern itself with timers.